# Read data from an array list, split and store in another

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am facing a problem in reading data from the text file line by line storing it in an arraylist. I have to read the data from `arraylist[0]` and I have to perform `split` operation on that data and I have to store the data in a different array.

```
public class StatsOnData {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    String gender;


     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file path"));
        String str;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`enter code here`
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(str);
        }

        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(list.size());


        //spliting the array into a sub array
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=1; i <= list.size(); i++){
           for( int j = 0; j < list[i]; j++){

              String line = null;

            while ((line = .readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split("|");
                for (String str1 : values) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

           }

        }
```

Comment: whats the problem. How would **`j < list[i]`** compile. Whats he use of `temp`. why are you reading again after it finished already

Comment: There seems no relation of while loop with constructed list. Whats the point of nesting that inside for loop

Comment: I have to split the data in list[0] and save it another array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your problem but may be you want to do something like this -

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file path"));
String str;
int countMale=0;
int countFemale=0;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    list.add(str);
}

for(String s:list){
    String[] splitValues=s.split("|");
    for(int i=0;i<splitValues.length;i++){
        if(splitValues[i].equalsIgnoreCase("m")){
            countMale++;
        }
        else if(splitValues[i].equalsIgnoreCase("f")){
            countFemale++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of males: "+countMale);
System.out.println("Number of females: "+countFemale);
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

To print content of each line in split form,

```
for(int i=1; i <= list.size(); i++)
{
      String line = list.get (i) ;
      String[] values = line.split("|");
      for (String str1 : values) 
      {
                System.out.print(str);
      }
}
```

You can even use map

```
Map<String,List<String>> genderNameList = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
for(int i=1; i <= list.size(); i++)
{
      String line = list.get (i) ;
      String[] values = line.split("|");
      //assuming it won't be null 
      genderNameList.get ( values[1]).add(values[0]);// need tot take care about null 
}
```

If your string goes like peter||Mr|F||23

```
List<Person> listOfObj = new ArrayList<Person> ();
for(int i=1; i <= list.size(); i++)
{
      String line = list.get (i) ;
      String[] values = line.split("|");
      //assuming it won't be null 
      Person p = new Person ( values) ;

}
```

And person can be as following :

```
Class Person {
  private String name;
  private String gender;
  private int age; 

  //provide gettter and setter for all such fields. 
  Person ( String [] values)
  {
     name = values[0];
     gender = values[1];
     age = Integer.valuesOf ( values[2]) ;

    .... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi What I am exactly trying to do is I have a text file named as Vicky.txt which contain data as  peter|M| in the first line and Kevin|F| in the second line now I have to read the file and Display how may male and how many female people are there.

Comment: First part of reading file  you have already done. For next thing I have given you solution

Comment: What if the data in text file is like this in first line peter||Mr|F|| and in the second line Kristen|James|Mr|M|True...observe there is an empty filed in between in ||.

Comment: In that case just split in array and all the fields to a class object. Yes i would suggest you to use a class. Create objects using these array values and add them to list

Comment: can you give me an example for this

Comment: I have given you full code. For any further requirements you can customize the code as you want.